# Cannot post a piece in apostrophe through headless api

Tags: postman, http-status-code-404, apostrophe-cms

I am using postman for adding piece through headless, i have been follwing the apostrophe-headless docs for this.
Now I got stuck on adding a apostrophe-image.
This is where I got stuck:(
[check this portion from apostrophe-headless docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buK9j.png)

I have got the attached field resulting json when i hit the api/v1/attachements

[Here it is...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5qGM.png)

Now i send this object as the value of any attachment schema field when communicating with the REST API.
This is how i have given the attachment in api/v1/apostrophe-images
and i dont return any JSON, instead it is showing a 404 error.[Please look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ELVY.png).
Is this the correct way to add attachment? here 'result' is the json file I got back from the attachment API

Comment: Please include what your full request looks like.

Comment: @alexbea No sir, Actually things are going great now.. i  refused to  continue with the above shared media methodology and instead i used the alternative method(directly accessing image) through snapshot property. Now everything is fine. Thanks for your concern sir.